# Can Technomancers change the appearance of their Persona?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, technomancer

I don't recall if there is any flavor text for or against this, but is a Technomancer's Matrix Persona's appearance fixed, or can it be changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Persona's *icon* can be changed, yes. They have a persona that follows the same rules as "normal" personas:

> A persona is a firmware program built into the device’s hardware that
>   you use to interact with the Matrix, in AR and in VR. It allows you to
>   perceive the digital world and projects your icon (or icons) into
>   nodes. Without a persona, you would be unable to access the Matrix.
>   Even technomancers have a (living) persona.

All personas have icons:

> Your persona is represented by an icon in the Matrix, as are your
>   running programs, files, agents, IC, links to nodes, etc.

And icons can be modified through the Alter/Swap Icon, which is not specific to hackers, and available to Technomancers as well:

> **Alter/Swap Icon (System)**
>
> You change a detail of an icon representing your persona or one of the
>   programs, files, or nodes you own, or switch the icon to a
>   pre-rendered icon you have stored.

Comment: So yes, you can change it to that hilarious cat picture with the caption.